# Why is this a call by value, altough I am passing a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Hi can somebody please explain why the following is a call by value?

I thought when I pass the **client** variable to GetClient it would be a call by reference.
But debbuging the code, showed me that only the parameter of GetClient is set and after leaving the method the **client** declared in main is still empty.

How do I have to define GetClient(), that it sets my client variable properly?
main

```
int main()
{
    Example::A a;
    Example::B b;
    Example::B* client = 0;
    a.SetClient(1,&b);
    a.GetClient(1,client);
    if(client != 0)
    {
        std::cout<<"OK"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

class A

```
namespace Example
{
 class A 
 {
 public:
    void A::SetClient(int key, B* client)
    {
        clients[key] = client;
    }
    void A::GetClient(int key, B* client)
    {
     client = clients[key];
    }
 private:
    B* clients[10];
 };
}
```

class B

```
class B 

namespace Example
{

  class B
  {

  private:
      int secret;
  };

}
```

Comment: The parameter `client` in the `GetClient` function has no purpose and does nothing.

Comment: This is **not** a minimal example. A minimal example would be something like `void f(int a) { a = 10; } int main() { int n = 0; f(n); std::cout << n << '\n'; }`

Comment: Because you aren't passing anything by reference. You are passing pointers by value.

Comment: You are passing the pointer by value.

Comment: @juanchopanza ohh now this seems very clear. Does this mean I need something like GetClient(int key, B** client)

Comment: @R_Valdez: `B *GetClient(int key)` would be more typical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass pointers by copy, so modifying them in the function does not modify the original passed parameters. If you want to pass them by reference to be able to modify the originals, use the following syntax :

```
void A::GetClient(int key, B*&client) {
  client = clients[key];
}
```

`client` is a reference to a pointer to `B`.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer is a reference to a `B` object, not a reference to the variable `client`. If you want a reference to the `client` variable you can either:

(1) Use the `&` operator on the function:

```
void A::GetClient(int key, B* & client)
{
     client = clients[key];
}
```

(2) Or, pass a pointer to the variable:

```
void A::GetClient(int key, B** client)
{
     *client = clients[key];
}
```

and pass the pointer of the variable:

```
a.GetClient(1, &client);
```